# Ifelse across multiple columns matching on similar attributes

Tags: r

I need to create a binary variable called dum, (perhaps using an ifelse statement) matching on the number of the column names.

ifelse f[number] %in% c(4:6) & l[number]==1, 1, else 0

```
f1<-c(3,2,1,6,5)
f2<-c(4,1,5,NA,NA)
f3<-c(5,3,4,NA,NA)
f4<-c(1,2,4,NA,NA)
l1<-c(1,0,1,0,0)
l2<-c(1,1,1,NA,NA)
l3<-c(1,0,0,NA,NA)
l4<-c(0,0,0,NA,NA)

mydata<-data.frame(f1,f2,f3,f4,l1,l2,l3,l4)
```

dum is 1 if f1 contains values between 4, 5, 6 AND l1 contains a value of 1, OR f2 contains values between 4, 5, 6 AND l2 contains a value of 1, and so on.

In essence, the expected output should be

```
  f1 f2 f3 f4 l1 l2 l3 l4 dum
1  3  4  5  1  1  1  1  0   1
2  2  1  3  2  0  1  0  0   0
3  1  5  4  4  1  1  0  0   1
4  6 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA   0
5  5 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA   0
```

I can only think of doing it in a very long way such as

```
mutate(dum=ifelse(f1 %in% c(4:6 & l1==1, 1, 
ifelse(f2 %in% c(4:6) & l2==1, 1, 
ifelse(f3 %in% c(4:6) & l3==1, 1, 
ifelse(f4 %in% c(4:6) & l4==1, 1, 0))))
```

But this is burdensome since the real data has many more columns than that and can go up to f20 and l20.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you please show your expected output?

Comment: Do you need  `mydata %>% mutate(dum = +(rowSums(across(starts_with('f'),  ~.x %in% 4:6) & across(starts_with('l'), ~ .x %in% 1)) > 0))`

Comment: Do you mean to create a "dum" column for EVERY pair of "f" and "l" columns, or just one "dum" column that checks to see if ANY pairs meet your conditions? Your code is unclear.

Comment: Sorry! I edited it. Please let me know if it's sufficiently clear.

Comment: @akrun what is this +() function? This works but I've never seen this before.

Comment: @kna123 it is just a way to coerce to binary i.e. `+(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))` or use `as.integer(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))`, as TRUE/FALSE are `1` and `0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion. Again it is not exactly clear. Assuming you want one column with `dum` that indicates the presences of the number in the column names in that row in any of the columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

mydata %>% 
  mutate(across(f1:l4, ~case_when(. == parse_number(cur_column()) ~ 1,
                                  TRUE ~ 0), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  mutate(sumNew = rowSums(.[9:16])) %>% 
  mutate(dum = ifelse(sumNew >=1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  select(1:8, dum)
```

```
  f1 f2 f3 f4 l1 l2 l3 l4 dum
1  3  4  5  1  1  1  1  0   1
2  2  1  3  2  0  1  0  0   1
3  1  5  4  4  1  1  0  0   1
4  6 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA   0
5  5 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `across` - loop `across` the 'f' columns, use the first condition, loop `across` the 'l' columns' with the second condition applied, join them together with `&` to return a logical matrix, get the row wise sum of the columns (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0), check if that sum is greater than 0 (i.e. if there are any TRUE in that row), and coerce the logical to binary with `+` or `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(dum = +(rowSums(across(starts_with('f'),  ~.x %in% 4:6) & 
                     across(starts_with('l'), ~ .x %in% 1)) > 0))
  f1 f2 f3 f4 l1 l2 l3 l4 dum
1  3  4  5  1  1  1  1  0   1
2  2  1  3  2  0  1  0  0   0
3  1  5  4  4  1  1  0  0   1
4  6 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA   0
5  5 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA   0
```

---

We could also use `base R`

```
mydata$dum <- +(Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x, y) x %in% 4:6 & 
          y %in% 1, mydata[startsWith(names(mydata), "f")], 
                    mydata[startsWith(names(mydata), "l")])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach multiplying two `mapply`s together, columns identified with `grep`, then calculating `rowSums > 0`. If you set `na.rm=F` you could get `NA`s in respective rows.

```
as.integer(rowSums(mapply(`%in%`, mydata[grep('^f', names(mydata))], list(4:6))*
            mapply(`==`, mydata[grep('^l', names(mydata))], 1), na.rm=T) > 0)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0
```

If `f*` and `l*` each aren't consecutive, rather use `sort(grep(., value=T))`.